# Overriding multiple virtual functions in a variadic class template

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Let me just give a code example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template <typename Service>
struct SubscriberImpl {
    virtual void handleService(Service const&) = 0;
};

template <typename...ServiceType>
struct Subscriber : SubscriberImpl<ServiceType>... {

};

struct IntService {};
struct FloatService {};

template <typename StatusUpdatePolicy, typename... ServiceType>
struct StatusUpdater : Subscriber<ServiceType...>
{
    StatusUpdater(StatusUpdatePolicy const& statusUpdater)
    : m_statusUpdater{statusUpdater}
    {}
    // wont work
    void handleService(IntService const& service) override {
        m_statusUpdater.updateService(service);
    }

    void handleService(FloatService const& service) override {
        m_statusUpdater.updateService(service);
    }

    StatusUpdatePolicy m_statusUpdater;
}; 

struct DummyPolicy {
    void updateService(IntService const& service) {
        m_i = 42;
        std::cout << m_i << "\n";
    }

    void updateService(FloatService const& service) {
        m_f = 3.14f;
        std::cout << m_f << "\n";
    }

    int m_i;
    float m_f;
};
int main() {

    StatusUpdater<DummyPolicy, IntService, FloatService> su(DummyPolicy{}); 

    su.handleService(IntService{});
    su.handleService(FloatService{});
}
```

Here `Subscriber` has a pure virtual function `handleService(ServiceType const)` for each template parameter in pack `ServiceType...`. So I have to override each one on `StatusUpdater`. Here, I have provided the ones I need by hand for `IntService` and `FloatService`, knowing I will be only needing those in this minimal example. But I want to be able to provide an override for whatever there is in the pack `ServiceType...`. All of them will call `updateService` method of the given policy anyways.

Please note that `Subscriber` comes from an external library and I cannot modify its definition.

Comment: Added MCVE for a specific case.

Comment: I second @Angew, moreover the indirection with `Service` -> `ServiceImpl` brings more problems than it solves.

Comment: That part is in a library we are using I am afraid, I don't have a chance to change `Subscriber`. I have to subscribe to services using that library and handle updating the status messages depending on that. Some of the messages require info from multiple services, that is why I am trying to come up with such a solution on my part rather than library part.

Comment: I've edited my answer to solve this (more complex) situation. Please use as a reminder that MCVEs are important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot put such implementations directly into the class, you have to inherit them (similarly to how `Subscriber` inherits from multiple `SubscriberImpl` instantiations). However, to override them all and still keep your class polymorphically usable as a `Subscriber`, you will have to inherit them "sequentially" instead of "in parallel." Additionally, the [Curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) can be used to give all the implementations access to the final overriding object:

```
template <class Self, class SubscriberClass, class... ServiceTypes>
struct StatusUpdaterOverride;


template <class Self, class SubscriberClass, class ThisType, class... RemainingTypes>
struct StatusUpdaterOverride<Self, SubscriberClass, ThisType, RemainingTypes...> : StatusUpdaterOverride<Self, SubscriberClass, RemainingTypes...>
{
  void handleService(ThisType const& service) override
  {
    static_cast<Self*>(this)->m_statusUpdater.updateService(service);
  }
  using StatusUpdaterOverride<Self, SubscriberClass, RemainingTypes...>::handleService;
};


template <class Self, class SubscriberClass, class ThisType>
struct StatusUpdaterOverride<Self, SubscriberClass, ThisType> : SubscriberClass
{
  void handleService(ThisType const& service) override
  {
    static_cast<Self*>(this)->m_statusUpdater.updateService(service);
  }
};


template <class StatusUpdatePolicy, class... ServiceType>
struct StatusUpdater : StatusUpdaterOverride<StatusUpdater<StatusUpdatePolicy, ServiceType...>, Subscriber<ServiceType...>, ServiceType...>
{
    StatusUpdater(StatusUpdatePolicy const& statusUpdater)
    : m_statusUpdater{statusUpdater}
    {}

    StatusUpdatePolicy m_statusUpdater;
};
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d7c1c763f190e30)

Comment: It is important for me though, that `StatusUpdater` can be used as a `Subscriber` object. When I inherit from `StatusUpdateOverride`, can my `StatusUpdater` still be used polymorphically through a `Subscriber *`? Could you also check the edit, I did a little typo on the code that could make a lot difference.

Comment: @meguli Polymorphism or virtual functions doesn't stop working no matter how deep the inheritance hierarchy get. If a function is marked as `virtual` once in a base class, it will stay `virtual` all the way down.

Comment: I could not get this to work and recursive template instantiation messes my mind. Could you share it on MCVE, if that is what you did on the first place?

Comment: @meguli Sorry, fixed (and mcve added). *Yes, I will take this as a reminder that MCVEs are important ;-)*

Answer (score 3):

I can't see a solution to do exactly what you want. However you can achieve the same behavior without needing the `virtual`ity at all. I initially thought about a CRTP solution just like @Angew's answer and then came up with another possibility:

You could edit your `Subscriber` class like this:

```
template <typename ServiceType>
class Subscriber {
public:
    template <typename Handler>
    void handleService(ServiceType const& service, Handler&& hdler) {
        // Maybe give `updateService` a broader name that can extend to other service handlers
        std::forward<Handler>(hdler).updateService(service);
    }
};
```

With that, your client code becomes:

```
template <typename StatusUpdatePolicy, typename... ServiceType>
struct StatusUpdater : Subscriber<ServiceType>...
{
    StatusUpdater(StatusUpdatePolicy const& statusUpdater)
    : m_statusUpdater{statusUpdater}
    {}
    template <typename ServiceT>
    void handleService(ServiceT const& service) override {
        Subscriber<ServiceT>::handleService(service, m_statusUpdater);
    }

    StatusUpdatePolicy m_statusUpdater;
};
```